# Exactly same folder and drive?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, partitioning

I had just one drive named C (500 GB). I recently partitioned it into 2 that is, C drive and E drive. I was transferring all the default folders (Music, Pictures, Videos, Downloads, Desktop and Documents) from C to E. Everything got transferred smoothly except the Music folder. Now, the music folder has been named as E:\ and there is already another drive named E:\ . I want the folder named E:\ to be named as Music and also it should contain only music.

Main view:

[image: Main view]

Following is the screen when I open the folder:

[image: Following is the screen when I open the folder]

The same things that are in the folder are there when I open the drive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
Per the conversation in the comment thread below it seems that you just want to delete the entry from the `Folders` pane in the first screen shot.

There's no known feature in Windows 10 that allows you to do so, but there is a [free 3rd party tool named "This PC Tweaker"](http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.213) that will help you accomplish this.

---

*(original answer - retained since there are comments about it and this answer was accepted based on those comments before I could post a new answer to be accepted)*

I'm not sure I fully understand what you're asking, but try this.

Edit the `desktop.ini` file shown in your second screen shot and change the value of `LocalizedResourceName` to the name you want to be displayed.

For example:

```ini
[.ShellClassInfo]
LocalizedResourceName=Music
InfoTip=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-12689
IconResource=%SystemRoot%\system32\imageres.dll,-108
IconFile=%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll
IconIndex=-237
```

You'll probably need to log out and back in to Windows again before the changes will be effective.  You may be able to get away with closing all your Explorer windows, but this seems inconsistent.

Comment: Will this just change the name or the contents inside as well? I would have posted 2 more screenshots and it would make the question clear but it says I need 2000 reputation points to post more than 2 links

Comment: It will only change the name.  What are you trying to change in the contents?  Each of the folders in your second screen shot also have their own `desktop.ini` files that can be used to change their appearance if that's of any help.  But, it sounds like you wanted E: drive to only contain music... so why not just remove all the folders other than `Music`?  Or better yet, delete them all (other than `Music`), move all the contents of `Music` to the root of `E:`, and then delete `E:\Music` also.

Comment: You do realize the `E:\` in the `Folders` pane is the same exact location as the `New volume (E;)` in the `Devices and Drives` pane, right?  (At least if I'm understanding the situation correctly)  It's just a link to the same location.

Comment: Yes exactly, they both direct me to the same place. I want the folder to direct me to Music and the drive should remain unchanged

Comment: How can I delete that folder named E:\ ?

Comment: Not sure of an easy way within Windows itself, but [this link](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-add-custom-folders-in-this-pc-in-windows-10-or-remove-the-defaults/) suggests using a free piece of software to edit the folders that show up there.  (I've never used it and cannot vouch for it)

Comment: If I delete that folder, will my drive remain unchanged? (the data in the drive won't be deleted if I delete the folder, right?)

Comment: Delete using what method?  The software from the link I provided?  As I said, I've never used it. I'm sure that it's not *supposed* to delete the actual folder.

Comment: The software works well and I have solved my problem. Thanks!